# Data Warehouse - How to create a Fact Table interecting all dimensions with R and/or SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r, data-warehouse, fact

I am trying to create a **Fact Table using 4 dimensions and 2 Files** and i haven't been able to connect all the information. I usually work with python but now i must use this with **R and SQL**.
I know exactly how i should connect all the info, but i don't know how to create de **SQL Queries** to do it. So if anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

First of all, i'll describe the **Dimensions** and then **Files**. Next i'll explain what is my idea to connect everything and retrieve the rows for fact Table

### **4 DIMENSIONS**

1. **Dimension Spectators**:   (2000 entries)

   ```
   ID, Spectator Code, Region, Genre, age class
   ```
2. **Dimension Hour**:  (1440 entries)

   ```
   ID, Hour, Minute, Complete Hour(HH:MM:SS), Period of the day
   ```
3. **Dimension Date**: (365 entries)

   ```
   ID, Year, Month, Day, Complete Date (YYYY:MM:DD), Day of the week
   ```
4. **Dimension Programs**: (60000 entries)

   ```
   ID, Station, Name of Program, Start hour of the program (HH:MM:SS), Duration(seconds), Complete Date (YYYY:MM:DD)
   ```

### **2 FILES**

After the dimensions I have 2 other files

1. **Audiences**: (2.2million entries)

   ```
   Id (The same as Spectators File), Complete Date(YYYY:MM:DD), station, Duration of visualization(minutes), Start
   ```

   of visualization(HH:MM:SS), End of visualization(HH:MM:SS)
2. -**Spectators File**: (300000 entries)

   ```
   Id(The same as Audiences File), Spectator Code(The same as Spectators Dimension), region, genre, age class
   ```

Somehow, i would like to do the **fact table (based on Audiences File)** using this format for each row of the table:

-**ID of the Spectators dimension** || Interacting ID Audience with ID of Spectators File then Code from Spectators File with Spectators Dimension

-**ID of the Date Dimension** || Interacting Complete Date from Audiences with Complete Date from Date Dimension

-**ID of the Hour  Dimension** - Start Visualization || Interacting Complete Hour from Audiences with Complete Hour from Hour Dimension

-**ID of the Hour  Dimension** - End visualization || Interacting Complete Hour from Audiences with Complete Hour from Hour Dimension

-**ID of the Program Dimension** (Interacting Complete Day, Station and the Interval between Start and Snd of visualization from Audiences **with** Complete Day, Station and Interval created by Start of Program + Duration of Program Dimension) The visualization of a spectator must be between the duration of program to assume a Row in fact table

-**Duration of visualization** from Audiences

---

- If you have reached this far, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

---

Comment: How far have you got?  Have you [staged the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data))?  If so, are you struggling to [transform the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load#Transform) into your desired format?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have 4 dimensions and 2 files, may I assume that all are present as data frames on R? Or are the 4 dimensions some external RDBMS tables that you need to connect using R? (For some reason, I cant comment on your question and hence writing it in answers here). 
If all data frames are present in R environment, then you can use a **merge** to merge the files, or SQLDF package to write SQL statements.

Comment: Hey! Yes, i have all Dimensions and Files in R dataframes. My only idea is really to use the SQLDF package the problem is that i don't have enough knowledge in Sql to do it 

Comment: sqldf("select * from Spectators left join Audiences on Spectators.ID=Audiences.ID")   try this for the first point.